# (i)PDB post mortem when using 'unittest discover'

Tags: python, debugging, python-unittest, pdb, ipdb

Most of the times when I run my tests, I do this via `python -m unittest discover` (I'm lazy).

Lets say that one of the tests raises an exception. Is there a way to make unittest framework run a post-mortem on it (preferably `ipdb.pm()`), without modifying the code of the tests?

I know I could add it directly to the code, but since I also use automatic runners / GitlabCI, I don't want those to hang up on the pdb shell.

Comment: https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/192